# Ventajas JQuery frente Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimización

lo primero de todo es que no quiero que a esta pregunta se le hagan respuestas de opinión y por tanto que no sea considerada como tal por la moderación de la comunidad.

Todos los que hemos usamos o hemos usado `JQuery` sabemos que una vez que te haces a la estructura de la librería puedes programar en menos líneas de código que de la forma normal.

Las librerías de  `jQuery` son bastante ligeras pero quería saber si alguien puede demostrar que sea más o menos rápido la ejecución de `Javascript`  usando las librerías o sin usarlas. 
Un saludo a toda la comunidad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respuesta rápida: la ejecución de una aplicación usando JavaScript puro siempre va a ser más rápida que usando bibliotecas como jQuery.

Ahora, no te lo tomes a mal, pero parece que tu pregunta se basa en algunas ideas equivocadas:

- "*puedes programar en menos líneas de código que de la forma normal*"
- "*quería saber si alguien puede demostrar que sea más o menos rápido la ejecución de Javascript usando las librerías o sin usarlas*"

> *puedes programar en menos líneas de código que de la forma normal*

Que el código con jQuery ocupe menos líneas que si lo hubieses hecho con JavaScript puro no quiere decir que haya menos líneas de código, no debes olvidarte de todas las líneas de código que la biblioteca incluye de por sí y que están realizando todas esas operaciones y líneas de código que te estás "ahorrando" con jQuery.

De hecho, a no ser que estés usando todas las funciones disponibles en la biblioteca, usando una biblioteca vas a estar procesando código que luego no usarás. Por eso es sólo una falsa idea de ahorro.

Más aún, puedes encontrarte con que estás realizando más operaciones de las que piensas/esperabas (especialmente con versiones antiguas de jQuery). Esto se debe a que jQuery realizará operaciones adicionales para asegurarse de que los comandos van a ser compatibles con los diferentes navegadores y plataformas (algo que puede no importar en tu caso particular, pero que sí importa a jQuery).

> *quería saber si alguien puede demostrar que sea más o menos rápido la ejecución de Javascript usando las librerías o sin usarlas*

No debes olvidar que una biblioteca JavaScript es sólo eso, una biblioteca: un juego de operaciones/funciones que se usan para extender el lenguaje (JavaScript) y que no tienen sentido por sí solas.

Son básicamente un "abrigo" que se pone por encima de JavaScript para complementarlo, lo van a hacer más *bonito* pero no más rápido. El código de jQuery es JavaScript. jQuery es sólo una interfaz para funciones que podría desarrollar el programador desde cero.

Entonces, ¿serían las funciones más rápidas si las desarrollase el programador en lugar de usar jQuery? Puede que sí o puede que no. Eso va a depender de la habilidad del desarrollador (jQuery y otras bibliotecas ya se han pulido y depurado y se sabe que funcionan y lo hacen de manera eficiente), pero si el código en JavaScript puro que se generase fuese similar al código interno de jQuery, entonces, la opción de JavaScript puro va a ser igual o más rápida (al menos ahorraría los gastos relacionados con las llamadas a funciones).

Resumiendo (creo que estoy dando muchos rodeos y no me estoy explicando bien): JavaScript puro sería más rápido... pero eso no quiere decir que no se deban usar bibliotecas: hacen el trabajo más sencillo y, en muchos casos, la diferencia va a ser tan mínima que realmente no va a importar (a no ser que necesites una aplicación en la que el tiempo de ejecución sea un factor crítico).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te has explicado perfectamente. También cuando decía en menos líneas me refería de cara al programador. Un saludo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hola, que es mejor entonces javascript puro, o jquery... En los nuevos navegadores con nueva versiones habría incompatibilidad con javascript puro. ¿Me quedó dudas y es interesante está pregunta? Saludos!